# Django admin changelist - link to related model change page

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

Is there a built-in way to tell `Django` to show links to related models in `changelist`?

If we have models `School` and `Student`, I want display `School` in `Student` changelist as a link to `School` object change page.

I can do that old way:

```
class StudentAdmin(..):
    list_display = [...,'school',...]

    def school(..):
        return mark_safe(..link..)
```

Is there a built in way? Something like:

```
class StudentAdmin(..):
    ...
    related_change_links = ['school']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something custom I believe that's the most *pythonic* way of doing that. Otherwise I guess that [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) should solve your issue.

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html


def school(self, instance):
    school_id = instance.school.pk
    info = (School._meta.app_label, School._meta.model_name)
    url = reverse('admin:{}_{}_change'.format(*info), args=(school_id,))

    return format_html('<a href="{url}">{text}</a>'.format(
        url=url,
        text=school_id))
```

Comment: I don't get "that's the most pythonic way of doing that", what is? The link you mention `list_display_links` links the field to the object itself, not to the related object.

Comment: You asked for a built-in way of doing that but that doesn't exist in this case, AFAIK. So, by "most pythonic way" I meant it's the most used way of doing it and I'm referring to the `def school()` function

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a built-in way. Defining your own read-only field for it, as you show in your question, is the right way to do it.

You could try to subclass `ModelAdmin` to add your own `related_change_links` property, if you want to use that in many places. That would entail overriding the `__init__` function to add the fields to `read_only_fields` and overriding `__getattr__` to dynamically create the getters for these fields.